# Should I try to decouple activities from their fragments in an Android app?

Tags: java, android, architecture

I have a main class that swaps in a few different fragments. Those fragments also have to invoke methods on their parent Activity class, therefore the Activity and Fragments are tightly coupled. Would it be worthwhile or better practice to decouple these or are fragments commonly coupled with their parent activities?